# keras mse adam val_loss much lower than nrmse?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, loss-functions, tensorflow

I'm trying to make sense of the `keras.models.Sequential` reported `val_loss`.  It is a much better `fit` (0.015 `val_loss` set to `mse` as the `loss` function) than the very large normalized root mean squared error (96%) (`mse` of the **model** divided by the 0.6 rms of the **actual**) would indicate (.96=`mse`/`rms` implies `mse` = .96*0.6 = **0.576, vary far from 0.015**). Moreover, the pearson r correlation coefficient (50%) and scatter doesn't look nearly that bad (h=**actual**, v=**model**):

[image]

Is there something funny about the `adam` optimizer I'm using in conjunction with the `mse` loss function that could end up misreporting a convergence between **model** and **actual**?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Could you try reading your question & editing to make it more clear? It's hard to say what are the metrics you are referring to, & comparing what to what?

Comment: `keras` terminology is highlighted.  It overlaps so much with standard terminology I thought it unecessary to provide further clarification.  What terms are unclear? `adam` may be one.  Are there others?

Comment: I don't mean terminology but things like "0.015 against a targeted rms 0.6" what is compared to what in here? What exactly is the "very large normalized root mean squared error (96%)"? Where did those numbers come from? The correlation coefficient is about correlation of what with what? Your plot does not have axis labels, so it is unclear what does it show.

Comment: I expanded the question, made terms consistent and added definition of v and h axes.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you mean. You have validation MSE=0.015, and RMSE=0.96, so what? What is wrong with those numbers?

Comment: I broke out the calculation so as to compare the `val_loss` to the `mse` implied by the `nrmse`.

Comment: You would need to give us more details about your data, on how did you exactly calculate those values, & the exact output you're seeing. Without this it is hard to comment. It is rather unlikely that software with such big number of users & developers would give totally wrong results for such a basic thing, so maybe you have some kind of bug in your code, or reasoning. If you give us more details, someone could help.